# How does a foreign key get into a table?

Tags: php, mysql

thanks in advance for any help.

I have a question about foreign keys. I understand the concept of having the data from one table inserted into another for reference. But my question is, how does it get there?

Currently I have two tables and two forms. One form inserts data into table A, the other form inserts into B. Then I use a function to get the id from the last insert into A and insert it into B. Is this the proper way to do this or am I missing something?

Comment: You insert into table `A`, you fetch the `last_insert_id()` made by that query and you use that id while inserting into `B` and yes, that's the proper way and you're not missing anything.

Comment: yes, I'm using that function. thank's for the confirmation, I'm glad I'm not just hacking this.

Comment: You're not hacking anything and it's great you came to the conclusion yourself, just keep at it that way, it's really rewarding when you can come to a conclusion yourself. And yes, nearly everything in IT is actually straight-forward :)

Answer (score 6):

There are two possibilities :

- You know the primary key before the insertion in table A => Then your technique isn't the right one, since you're retrieving something you already added.
- You don't know it (Example: auto-incremented id's) => Then your technique is the right one, and I don't think there is any other better way to achieve what you are asking for.

Note that what I called the **primary key** is the **primary key** of the row in table A, and a **foreign key** for rows in table B.

Comment: Yes, that's the case, it's auto incremented so there is no id until after the insert. Thanks guys, that's a relief, I'm new to this stuff and figuring it out as I go along, I'm always worried I'm just hacking it, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, I don't believe you aren't missing anything. There are many ways to accomplish what you are after, but your explanation is probably the most used and straightforward.

Another way is to use a trigger on table A to populate table B after insert (this only works if you do not need any additional user input, like form input to insert into table B).

Answer (score -1):

As you cannot insert two ids at a time, yes it was an proper way.

- First inserting the record on primary table, which we knows it.
- Secondly, you that last insert id using the `mysqli_insert_id()` function
- Now insert data on foreign table using this primary key.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Just as an FYI though, `mysql_` commands are deprecated and are no longer support. You should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions instead.

Comment: Hello, see mysql_ is though still running on lakhs of application. It was just deprecated. Thus you can use mysql_ or mysqli_.